# Using ffmpeg to convert DTS audio track to AC3 and add back into MKV?

Tags: ffmpeg

My home audio system only supports Dolby (AC3) and not DTS. So if I want 5.1 surround sound, I have been using `ffmpeg` like so:

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -b:a 640k my_movie_ac2.mkv
```

This creates a separate file with the AC3 track instead of DTS. How do I instead just add the AC3 stream back into the MKV as an additional audio track? I'd like to keep the DTS track, but not have two, separate MKV files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k my_movie_ac2.mkv
```

See [Making ffmpeg process first audio stream differently than all others](https://superuser.com/q/1219784) for a guide to how stream specifiers are applied.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_VID.mkv -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a:0 -c:0:a:0 copy -disposition:a:0 1 -map 0:a:0 -c:0:a:1 ac3 -disposition:a:1 0 OUTPUT_VID.mkv
```

- `-map 0:v -c:v copy`  copies the Video
- `-map 0:a:0 -c:0:a:0 copy -disposition:a:0 1` copies the Original Audio as the 1st Positioned Audio (-c:a:0) and makes it default (disposition 1)
- `-map 0:a:0 -c:0:a:1 ac3 -disposition:a:1 0` converts the Audio to ac3 as the 2nd Positioned Audio (-c:a:1) and removes any default Flag to this position (disposition 0)

#ffmpeg #audio

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about converting all the audio tracks.

Since the command is different for each file depending on the number of audio tracks, I created a python script which creates the ffmpeg command and who executes it.

List Audio/subtitle track:

```
python3 allAudioToAC3.py scan -i /root/myfile.mkv
```

Convert all Audio track to AC3:

```
python3 allAudioToAC3.py convert -i /root/input.mkv -o /root/output.mkv
```

Or convert all Audio track to AC3 and remove input file:

```
python3 allAudioToAC3.py convert -i /root/input.mkv -o /root/output.mkv -r
```

Python3 script `allAudioToAC3.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import json
import subprocess
from argparse import ArgumentParser

cli = ArgumentParser()
subparsers = cli.add_subparsers(dest="subcommand")

def argument(*name_or_flags, **kwargs):
    """Properly format arguments to pass to the subcommand decorator"""
    if "default" in kwargs and "help" in kwargs:
        kwargs["help"] += " (default: {[default]})".format(kwargs)
    return (list(name_or_flags), kwargs)

def subcommand(args=[], parent=subparsers):
    """Decorator to define a new subcommand in a sanity-preserving way."""
    def decorator(func):
        name = func.__name__
        if name.endswith("_"):
            name = name[:-1]
        parser = parent.add_parser(name, description=func.__doc__)
        for arg in args:
            parser.add_argument(*arg[0], **arg[1])
        parser.set_defaults(func=func)
    return decorator

@subcommand([
    argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help="Input file")])
def scan(args):
    """Scan/Display all audio and subtitle"""
    audio_flag = False
    ffprobe_cmd = "ffprobe -hide_banner -show_streams -print_format json " + args.input
    process = subprocess.Popen(ffprobe_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
    output = json.loads(process[0])

    for stream in output["streams"]:
        if stream['codec_type'] == 'audio':
            audio_flag = True
            break;

    if audio_flag:
        print("audio present in the file")
    else:
        print("audio not present in the file")
        sys.exit(1)

    for stream in output["streams"]:
        if stream['codec_type'] == 'audio':
            print('--------------------------')
            print('AUDIO: Codec Format :', stream['codec_long_name'], stream['codec_name'])
            try:
                print('AUDIO: Language :', stream['tags']['language'])
            except:
                pass
            print('AUDIO: Piste index :', stream['index'])

        if stream['codec_type'] == 'subtitle':
            print('--------------------------')
            print('SUBTITLE: Codec Format :', stream['codec_long_name'], stream['codec_name'])
            try:
                print('SUBTITLE: Language :', stream['tags']['language'])
            except:
                pass
            print('SUBTITLE: Piste index :', stream['index'])

@subcommand([
    argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help="Input file"),
    argument("-o", "--output", required=True, help="Output File"),
    argument("-r", "--remove", action='store_true', help="Remove Input file")])
def convert(args):
    """Convert all audio to AC3"""
    audio_flag = False
    ffprobe_cmd = "ffprobe -hide_banner -show_streams -print_format json " + args.input
    process = subprocess.Popen(ffprobe_cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
    output = json.loads(process[0])

    for stream in output["streams"]:
        if stream['codec_type'] == 'audio':
            audio_flag = True
            break;

    if audio_flag:
        print("audio present in the file")
    else:
        print("audio not present in the file")
        sys.exit(1)

    pistes = []
    i = 0
    subtitle = ""
    for stream in output["streams"]:
        if stream['codec_type'] == 'audio':
            print('--------------------------')
            print('AUDIO: Codec Format :', stream['codec_long_name'], stream['codec_name'])
            try:
                print('AUDIO: Language :', stream['tags']['language'])
            except:
                pass
            print('AUDIO: Piste index :', stream['index'])
            pistes.append('-c:a:{} ac3'.format(i))
            i = i + 1

        if stream['codec_type'] == 'subtitle':
            print('--------------------------')
            print('SUBTITLE: Codec Format :', stream['codec_long_name'], stream['codec_name'])
            try:
                print('SUBTITLE: Language :', stream['tags']['language'])
            except:
                pass
            print('SUBTITLE: Piste index :', stream['index'])
            subtitle = " -c:s copy"


    audio = ' '.join(pistes)
    cmd = "ffmpeg -i {} -map 0 -c:v copy {}{} {}".format(args.input, audio, subtitle, args.output)
    print(cmd)
    os.system(cmd)

    if args.remove:
        print('Remove Input file:', args.input)
        os.remove(args.input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = cli.parse_args()
    if args.subcommand is None:
        cli.print_help()
        sys.exit()

    args.func(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this example, help-info.de :-)

I must remove a 0 because I get an error message…

> Invalid stream specifier 0:a:0

**Example**

- `-c:0:a:0` (not working)
- `-c:a:0` (working)

**Example for stream output assignment**

1. copy video from source
2. copy audio from source
3. create ac3 from audio source

Answer (score -1):

check out MKVToolNix: https://mkvtoolnix.download/

it'll let you alter mkv files like adding/removing audio streams.  would still be a two step process, but could probably script them together to a single call if desired.