# FFmpeg convert audio track and add back into media file without touching video track

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion

I want to convert an audio track to AC3 as efficiently and lossless as possible.

[This post gives the command:](https://superuser.com/a/1427601/1006358)

```
ffmpeg -i my_movie.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a -map 0:s -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k my_movie_ac2.mkv
```

Will this command ignore the video/subtitle tracks? Is there an FFmpeg command to convert and add back an audio track (e.g. convert DTS to AC3 and add into the original media file) **without** needing to copy the video/subtitle tracks? Or does the non-audio-track copying not take much time/resources?

Also, what does the `-c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k` mean? Should I change this depending on the original audio track? Is this the best possible conversion to AC3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this command ignore the video/subtitle tracks?

No. `-map 0:v` and `-map 0:s` will include the video and subtitles. `-c:v copy` and `-c:s copy` will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux without re-encoding) the video and subtitles.

> Is there an FFmpeg command to convert and add back an audio track (e.g. convert DTS to AC3 and add into the original media file) without needing to copy the video/subtitle tracks?

No. `ffmpeg` must make a new file. It is not able to edit-in-place.

> Or does the non-audio-track copying not take much time/resources?

Re-muxing does not take much time/resources compared to encoding.

> what does the `-c:a:0 ac3 -b:a:0 640k` mean?

- `-c:a:0 ac3` For audio output stream #0 use the encoder name ac3. Counting starts from 0 so this is the first output audio stream.
- `-b:a:0 640k` For audio output stream #0 apply a bitrate of 640k/s.

> Should I change this depending on the original audio track?

You can change it if you want to use a different encoder or bitrate.

> Is this the best possible conversion to AC3?

It's probably fine. Does it sound good? You may consider removing `-b:a:0 640k` and allow the encoder to automatically choose the bitrate depending on the channel layout (stereo, 5.1, etc).

The encoder ac3 has many additional options that you may want to review. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=ac3`. This is not an encoder I use so I am unable to provide detailed suggestions.