# ffmpeg: correct syntax for multiple audio filters

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I want to apply three audio filters: pan --> dynaudnorm --> volume.

The problem is that the middle filter (dynaudnorm) is ignored.

For testing, I've tried rearranging the filters, and no matter which filter is in the middle, it is ignored. I've also tried the 'label' syntax -- ie, [in]filter=args[out] --and the same problem occurs: the middle filter is skipped.

What am I missing?

```
ffmpeg -i "infile.mkv" -c:a mp3 -filter_complex "pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE[b], dynaudnorm=f=75:g=7; volume=0.5[2smash]" -map 0 -map [2smash] -metadata:s:a:[2smash] title="Low Dyn Range" -c:v copy "filtertest.mkv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a series of filters applied on a single audio stream, use a simple filterchain:

`ffmpeg -i "infile.mkv" -filter:a:1 "pan=stereo|FL=0.5*FC+0.707*FL+0.707*BL+0.5*LFE|FR=0.5*FC+0.707*FR+0.707*BR+0.5*LFE, dynaudnorm=f=75:g=7,volume=0.5" -map 0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -metadata:s:a:1 title="Low Dyn Range" "filtertest.mkv"`

I assume your input has a single audio stream.

Comment: Thanks, but the filters are completely ignored...
```
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (subrip (srt) -> ass (native))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:3 (ac3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
```
... confirmed by listening, and retesting with volume set to .01. Both output audio streams are identical.

Comment: For an output stream with a simple filterchain, mapping will show input and output index. Only complex graphs show disjoint mapping.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: Thanks for your help. https://pastebin.com/7AFVBvha

Comment: First, upgrade ffmpeg. 2.8 series is over 5 years old.  So, all filters are being applied but I overlooked that you are mapping the audio twice (first time, as part of -map 0), so change `-af` to `-filter:a:1`

Comment: Using ffmpeg static build 4.4 works! My sincere thanks. Whew. Could you provide a link or explanation for how the stream specifiers work with -filter and the 2nd -map  (For future readers, kindly edit your answer to include -filter:a:1)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1219784/